# How to parse an std object to get specific data

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, associative-array

I tried to convert this result to an array,I used json_decode() but I always got null then I used Service_json() and I solve the problem.

After that, I got this result but now I have a difficulty to get some specific data like categorie,nom, marque and their values and I got empty result.

Here is the array:

```
array(1) {
  ["hits"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["hits"]=>
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "kN5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(29) "Bonbons parfums fruits MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "kd5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(21) "Bonbons menthe MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "kt5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(37) "Bonbons caramel/chocolat blanc MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "k95iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "Mentos"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(31) "Bonbons caramel/chocolat MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "lN5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#13 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(28) "Bonbons menthe sucres MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "ld5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(31) "Bonbons framboise orange MENTOS"
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      object(stdClass)#16 (2) {
        ["_id"]=>
        string(20) "lt5iEXIBfVAlCluoT3sT"
        ["_source"]=>
        object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
          ["categorie"]=>
          string(7) "Bonbons"
          ["marque"]=>
          string(6) "MENTOS"
          ["nom"]=>
          string(26) "Bonbons pomme verte MENTOS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I parse this array to get categorie nom and marque and their values?

Comment: I guess you are using Elasticsearch to get the hits, So you have hits in format `array of object`, Simple `foreach` will do the parse to get hits inside the hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but I guess this is what you need  to get inner element values using `foreach`,

```
foreach($result['hits']->hits as $key=>$value){
   echo $value->_source->categories, $value->_source->marque, $value->_source->nom.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer was helpful @Always

Comment: @Ana glad it helps you somehow, best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

See the example below for how to deal with your situation.

```
class Person implements JsonSerializable
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    public function __construct(array $data) 
    {
        $this->id = $data['id'];
        $this->name = $data['name'];
    }

    public function getId() 
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return 
        [
            'id'   => $this->getId(),
            'name' => $this->getName()
        ];
    }
}
$person = new Person(array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Amir'));
echo json_encode($person,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Getting your json result which is a string, to be able to iterate through, do something like:

```
$json = json_decode($json);
```

Loop through the object and get its members with something like:

```
foreach($json as $obj){
   echo $obj->name;
   .....

}
```

I hope this workflow helps you achieve what you desire.